# Android: good practices for organizing dirs and files on storage SD card?

Tags: android, file, resources, storage, sd-card

Are there any guidelines where should my app store resource files downloaded from internet?

Comment: I don't believe there are any particular guidelines published, but it's a good idea to create a dedicated directory for your application, rather than dumping everything in the root of the SD card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, now there are published guidelines:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is an advice [gleaned](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/6911993da5c82934?pli=1) from the android developers forum:

> There are two fairly common and well
> defined situations:
>
> Situation: You need a temp file to do
> some processing that won't necessarily
> fit into memory.
>
> Solution: Create the
> file, use it, delete it when you're
> done*  Caveat: The file may be
> exceptionally large: demand an SDCard.
> The file  contains sensitive
> information: use app storage.
>
> Situation: You are operating a cache.
>
> Solution: maintain the files in the
> supplied cache directory
> (Context.getCacheDir()), the system
> knows these can be deleted**  Caveat:
> Big ticket items (like songs and
> videos) go to the sdcard (the user
> can treat these types as useful files
> anyway)